# WPF: Using predefined colour in storyboard animation, for a buttons style within resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, styles, resourcedictionary

I am trying to write a `button` **style** which exists within its own resource dictionary. It should have a **basic animation** in which the button background fades from Dark grey to Light grey when the mouse moves over it.

The problem is that it seems not to like the fact that I am referencing a predefined colour by key **SPECIFICALLY** within the **storyboard**. I can't understand why this is because I'm fairly used to referencing existing resources.

An exception is raised at runtime:

```
"InvalidOperationException: Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads"
```

Below is the unfinished style for the button:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Style.Components.Buttons">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LargeFlatListOptionButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextParagraphWhiteP1}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundGreyLevel2}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ControlOutlineUnselected}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <!-- ANIMATIONS -->
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="{DynamicResource BackgroundGreyLevel2Color}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).Color" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The colour resource is defined here:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
...
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundGreyLevel2" Color="#FF464646" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextParagraphWhiteP1" Color="White" />
<Color x:Key="BackgroundGreyLevel2Color" >#FF464646</Color>
...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Of course, I can just write the color I want it to fade to inline, but I would far prefer to use the resource I've already defined, as if our style is updated from grey to e.g. blue; I would have to remember to change it here and in all other inline locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from [Microsoft Docs on Storyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview#animate-in-a-style).

> You can't use dynamic resource references or data binding expressions to set Storyboard or animation property values. That's because everything inside a Style must be thread-safe, and the timing system must freeze Storyboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource references or data binding expressions.

I can suggest some workarounds (what I've seen done), that may or may not work for you:

- Using `StaticResource` markup extension to reference the Color resource (it will work if you redefine the color resource, but won't allow users of your library to redefine it later). Then one could have a "base style" for buttons, and create specific styles for different colored buttons (you base it on that "base style" and add animations using `StaticResource`).
- Changing the `ControlTemplate` so that you have 2 different colored sufaces on top of each other (say you have a Border with light gray Background on top of a Border with dark gray Background), and then animate the `Opacity` of the top element. You basically fade out the top element. Those elements can use `DynamicResource` to set their properties.

Comment: djomlastic, thank you for your helpful response. May I ask what you mean in your first suggestion by "redefine the color resource"?

Comment: @BenHayward Well, if you change BackgroundGreyLevel2Color to be some other color (say red), but you don't change the key, your button will be  animated to red. The problem of StaticResource vs DynamicResource remains, so if a user of your library decides he wants BackgroundGreyLevel2Color to be gold (and not gray), the button will be animated to gray. I believe that second option might be better, I've seen that in control libraries.

Comment: @djomalstic I see - I tried simply changing the storyboard to To="{StaticResource BackgroundGreyLevel2Color}" but this also did not work. I see what you mean with your second suggestion - this might indeed be the best workaround. I shall give that a go! Many thanks

Comment: @BenHayward Simply changing to StaticResource should work, maybe the Storyboard.TargetProperty is not correct (those can be tricky). I've seen that second option done in libraries like MahApps.Metro (I couldn't swear it's that one, but I've seen it more than once).

Comment: @BenHayward Try using Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)".